# E2141 Declaration syntax error в cbuilder

Tags: c++, строки, c++builder

У меня есть следующий код:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit3.h"
#include <string>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TAdd_data *Add_data;

ifstream input;

string StrTostr (String n) {
    return AnsiString(n).c_str();
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TAdd_data::TAdd_data(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
```

Проблема собственно в этих строчках, как я понял:

```
string StrTostr (String n) {
    return AnsiString(n).c_str();
};
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Может будет достаточно написать `String` полностью в нижнем регистре (`string`)? Откуда Вы взяли такой тип?

Comment: Это UnicodeString, программа в CBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался, просто забыл поставить `using namespace std;`

Comment: Ничего себе исправленьице: поставить `using namespace std;`...